# Jetbrains Structural Search - Matching Constants

Tags: android-studio, search, jetbrains-ide, code-inspection, structural-search

I'm using Android Studio and I'm trying to create an inspection for myself to match all instances of a `View.INVISIBLE` - View is a class and INVISIBLE is a constant. If I have `View.INVISIBLE` in my structural search query it doesn't find instances of it as I would expect it.

[Here's the template under `Inspections > Structural Search Inspection`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I10WO.png)
[And here is it not applying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBPkp.png)

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to find references to the constant (similar to Find Usages)? Or could you provide some example code of what you are trying to find?

Comment: I'm trying to find that exact match, so yes similar to Find Usages.

Comment: It seems `View.INVISIBLE` should indeed find what you need. Perhaps you could still provide some example of the code you are trying to find?

Comment: I added some screenshots to show it not working

Comment: You seem to be editing the Default Settings (`File | Other Settings | Default Settings...`). These will only have effect when creating a new project.